filter a single string of ingredients that have all the ingredients from a list of strings
Im trying to filter recipes that have a single string of ingredients that have all the ingredients from resultData which is a list of strings. Cant figure how to do it. The current code rn only filters the recipe that have any ingredients from resultData.
here is the full code:


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:recipe_page_new/data_repository/dbHelper.dart';
import 'package:recipe_page_new/models/recipe_model.dart';
import 'package:recipe_page_new/ui/widgets/recipe_widget.dart';


// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ShowRecipeWithIngredients extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<RecipeModel> recipes;
  List<RecipeModel> filteredRecipes = [];
  final List<String> resultData;

  ShowRecipeWithIngredients({super.key, required this.recipes, required this.resultData}) {
    filteredRecipes = recipes;
  }

  @override
  State<ShowRecipeWithIngredients> createState() => _SearchRecipeScreenState();
}

class _SearchRecipeScreenState extends State<ShowRecipeWithIngredients> {

  void filterRecipe(String value) {
    setState(() {
      widget.filteredRecipes = widget.recipes
          .where((recipe) =>
              recipe.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  void _filterRecipes(List<String> resultData) {
    setState(() {
      widget.filteredRecipes = widget.recipes.where((recipe) {
        // Check if all ingredients in resultData are in the recipe's ingredients
        return resultData.any((ingredient) => 
          recipe.ingredients.contains(ingredient.toLowerCase())
        );
      }).toList();
      // test whel! 
      print(resultData);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _filterRecipes(widget.resultData);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: TextField(
          onChanged: (value) {
            filterRecipe(value);
          },
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            hintText: "Search Recipe",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: widget.filteredRecipes.isNotEmpty
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: widget.filteredRecipes.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return RecipeWidget(widget.filteredRecipes[index]);
                },
              )
            : const Center(
                child: Text('Recipe not found...'),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

help and answers please
